# dollar sign symbol is not working in React

Tags: reactjs, crud, dollar-sign

I am building a CRUD app with React. For the Product Edit page where I want to edit a specific product(clicked product), I need to grab the product's Id. I use the dollar symbol in the code but it doesn't get blue(it doesn't work). I need the URL to change the specific product showing its id when clicked. How to do that? What am I doing wrong?

`

```
<Link className='btn btn-primary m-2'><i className="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></ Link>
          <Link className='btn btn-otline-primary m-2' to={"/product/edit/${product.id}"}>Edit</Link>
          <Link className='btn btn-danger m-2'>Delete</Link>
```

`

```
const onSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await axios.put('http://localhost:3001/products/${id}', product);
  navigate.push("/");
  };
```

``

I thought when I clicked the Edit button I could see the Edit page for the specific product but instead it shows like this: http://localhost:3000/product/edit/$%7Bproduct.id%7D. Not an id after the editing part.

Comment: You need to use backticks (`\``) to use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Regular quotes (`"` or `'`) just create a string.

Comment: Now I remembered; Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Should be `` not `''`

```
 await axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/products/${id}`, product);
```

Answer (score 1):

Template literals are created using the `` ` `` symbol, this works:

```
let x = "def"
console.log(`abc${x}`);
// Prints: "abcdef"
```

But normal strings don't:

```
let x = "def"
console.log("abc${x}");
// Prints: "abc${x}"
```

See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to learn more about how template strings work.